# Compare file before and after several commits

Tags: github

I have some file in my GitHub repository. Another contributor has done 50 commits in a row. Now I want to understand what was changed.

**Is it possible to see all changes like it was one commit? Is it possible to do in a web interface or in GitHub Desktop?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want the "compare" feature of the web interface: https://help.github.com/articles/comparing-commits-across-time/